# Escape Sequences with Perl Unix Commands

Tags: linux, perl, git, unix, escaping

I am trying to execute the following unix command from within perl

```
`git log --pretty=format:%H | grep $id | wc -l`;
```

I keep getting an error saying

```
sh: -c : syntax error near unexpected token '|'
sh -c : '| wc -l'
```

How can I fix this error

Comment: You have Perl. Why are you using `grep` and `wc`?

Comment: Because I am using it to execute the external commands on terminal

Comment: Repeating the question is not an answer.

Comment: I was just trying to justify the  need of grep and wc commands in my script

Comment: Yes, that's what you were asked to do. What's your justification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have `123<NEWLINE>` instead of `123` in `$id`, so you're passing the following to the shell:

```
git log --pretty=format:%H | grep 123
 | wc -l
```

instead of

```
git log --pretty=format:%H | grep 123 | wc -l
```

Fix the value in `$id`. The best way is probably through [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).

Comment: Yes thats correct. I get an alphanumeric value in $id. But seeing the error I thought, I am missing the escape sequence may be

Comment: You missed the point. I said you DON'T have an alphanumeric value in `$id`. Read again. Maybe a little clearer with a little change I made.

Comment: @iDev - show us the code that is assigning $id.  It's very likely that this solution is correct, but a little more context would help nail it down.

Comment: That was a pretty good guess, @ikegami . I believe iDev has $id populated from another backquoted expression. Stackoverflow took the backquotes he had in his comment as a formatting hint, and that threw me off. You are correct, the result of that backquoted expression will likely have a trailing newline.

Comment: yes $id also had the backticks to grab the output. when I tried it manually on the terminal the command seemed to work fine and when I execute it through script I was getting a syntax error. Thanks theglauber , ikegami for your replied. It really helped :) Sorry for the typos in my question. Will be careful henceforth!

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have a more robust script if you implement some of this functionality using Perl subroutines instead of external Unix commands.

Using backquotes is good for a quick script, but it's inherently fragile, because you are exposed to the full power and weirdness of whatever Unix shell is configured for the user that is running your script (with wildcard expansion, input/output redirection, piping, etc.). This really applies to any programming language, and most languages (including perl) have safer ways to run external commands without using the shell. But one of the reasons Perl was created was to be able to combine under one programming language the text-processing abilities of a slew of Unix commands.

Comment: Probably a quoting problem, then. You may want to print the string you are generating, to see exactly what it is you're passing to the shell. I see a couple of special characters in the variable contents you specified above.

Comment: I tried debugging by printing on the terminal. It looks fine. But, when I guess its an issue of escaping the pipe.

Comment: No, undefined `$id` will not cause that error. See my answer.

Comment: If there's a way to do this more efficiently in perl, you should explain how. Otherwise this "answer" is not an answer at all, just perl elitism.

Comment: :-) Sorry about that. There was more in my "answer" but it got edited out (and i agree with the editor). Still i think this is a program design consideration, not perl elitism.